# Need to transform xhtml table to dita specific table with row span

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Need to transform xhtml table to dita specific table with row span

Basically, where ever there rowspan attribute with more than one td element, it should shift to the next column.

Current scenario post transformation:

[image: current scenario post transformation]

Expected scenario:

[image: Expected scenario]

I tried lot of things in xslt but somehow, I am unable to get the expected result.

**Current HTML table**

```html
        <table class="gripstable-LT-LineColor width-percent grid-all">
            <colgroup>
                <col />
                <col />
            </colgroup>
            <tbody class="body">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="6">
                        <p class="para-default">A</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(2) Front circuit supply</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(3) Rear circuit supply</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(4) Rear circuit control</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(5) Parking circuit supply</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(6) Parking circuit control</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(7) Front circuit delivery</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="6">
                        <p class="para-default">B</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(2) Rear circuit supply</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(3) Front circuit delivery</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(4) Rear circuit control</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(5) Parking circuit delivery</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(6) Parking circuit control</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(7) Load sensing valve supply</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">
                        <p class="para-default">C</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(1) Air supply</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(2) Air compressor governor signal</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="1">
                        <p class="para-default">D</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(2) Front parking circuit delivery</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3">
                        <p class="para-default">E</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(1) Trailer supply</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(2) Parking circuit control</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(3) Front circuit control</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="1">
                        <p class="para-default">F</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(1) Auxiliaries supply</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="1">
                        <p class="para-default">G</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="para-default">(1) Air suspension supply</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Expected dita table with morerows attribute in order for row span to work**

```html
        <table>
            <tgroup cols="2">
                <colspec colname="col1"></colspec>
                <colspec colname="col2"></colspec>
                <tbody>
                    <row>
                        <entry morerows="5">A</entry>
                        <entry>(2) Front circuit supply</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(3) Rear circuit supply</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(4) Rear circuit control</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(5) Parking circuit supply</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(6) Parking circuit control</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(7) Front circuit delivery</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry morerows="5">B</entry>
                        <entry>(2) Rear circuit supply</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(3) Front circuit delivery</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(4) Rear circuit control</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(5) Parking circuit delivery</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(6) Parking circuit control</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(7) Load sensing valve supply</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry morerows="1">C</entry>
                        <entry>(1) Air supply</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(2) Air compressor governor signal</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>D</entry>
                        <entry>(2) Front parking circuit delivery</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry morerows="2">E</entry>
                        <entry>(1) Trailer supply</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(2) Parking circuit control</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>(3) Front circuit control</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>F</entry>
                        <entry>(1) Auxiliaries supply</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry>G</entry>
                        <entry>(1) Air suspension supply</entry>
                    </row>
                </tbody>
            </tgroup>
        </table>
```

**Below is the xslt I tried**

```
 <xsl:if
            test="descendant::xhtml:table[@class = 'gripstable-LT-LineColor width-percent grid-all']">
            <table>
                <tgroup cols="2">
                    <colspec colname="col1"/>
                    <colspec colname="col2"/>
                    <xsl:if test="xhtml:div/xhtml:div/xhtml:div/xhtml:table/xhtml:thead">
                        <thead>
                            <xsl:for-each
                                select="xhtml:div/xhtml:div/xhtml:div/xhtml:table/xhtml:thead/xhtml:tr">
                                <row>

                                    <xsl:if test="xhtml:td[fn:position() = 1]">
                                        <entry>
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="xhtml:td[fn:position() = 1]//xhtml:p[@class = 'para-default']"
                                            />
                                        </entry>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="xhtml:td[fn:position() = 2]">
                                        <entry>
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="xhtml:td[fn:position() = 2]//xhtml:p[@class = 'para-default']"
                                            />
                                        </entry>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="xhtml:td[fn:position() = 3]">
                                        <entry>
                                            <xsl:value-of
                                                select="xhtml:td[fn:position() = 3]//xhtml:p[@class = 'para-default']"
                                            />
                                        </entry>
                                    </xsl:if>

                                </row>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </thead>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:for-each
                            select="xhtml:div/xhtml:div/xhtml:div/xhtml:table/xhtml:tbody/xhtml:tr">
                            <row>
                                <entry>
                                    <xsl:value-of
                                        select="xhtml:td[fn:position() = 1]/xhtml:p[@class = 'para-default']"
                                    />
                                </entry>
                                <entry>
                                    <xsl:value-of
                                        select="xhtml:td[fn:position() = 2]/xhtml:p[@class = 'para-default']"
                                    />
                                </entry>


                                <!-- <xsl:if test="xhtml:td[1]/@rowspan">
                                    <entry>
                                     <xsl:attribute name="morerows">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="xhtml:td[fn:position() = 1]/@rowspan"/>
                                   </xsl:attribute>
                                   <xsl:value-of select="xhtml:td[fn:position() = 1]/xhtml:p[@class = 'para-default']"/>
                                   </entry>
                                   
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    
                                    <xsl:if test="xhtml:td[2]">
                                    <entry>
                                   <xsl:value-of select="xhtml:td[fn:position() = 2]/xhtml:p[@class = 'para-default']"/>
                                   </entry>
                                   
                                    </xsl:if> -->
                            </row>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tbody>
                </tgroup>
            </table>
        </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can write templates to match and transform the different HTML elements and attributes to the target/dita counterparts:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="colgroup"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="colgroup">
    <tgroup cols="{count(col)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="col, ../tbody"/>
    </tgroup>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="col">
    <colspec colname="col{position()}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="tbody">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="tr">
    <row>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </row>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="th | td">
    <entry>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
    </entry>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="th/@* | td/@*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="th/@rowspan[. > 1] | td/@rowspan[. > 1]">
    <xsl:attribute name="morerows" select=". - 1"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In general, however, for complex but well-defined and broadly supported vocabularies like XHTML and Dita I would look whether there are existing libraries that implement the task at hand instead of trying to roll my own.

Comment: Can we do something in single template as we have many different types of table based on attribute, Different templates will not work out.

Comment: @ak5555, use different modes then.